# How to get Dynamic value via "GET" request in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Once I run the server, It got a static Date value which doesn't change,
How can I make it dynamic?

```
const app = express();
var d = new Date();
var key_1 = d.getMinutes();

app.get( "/time_in_minutes", (req, res) => {
    res.json(key_1.toString());   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you move those two lines into the request handler? This way a new date will be calculated for each response you send back. Try this:

```
app.get( "/time_in_minutes", (req, res) => {
  var d = new Date();
  var key_1 = d.getMinutes();
  res.json(key_1.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put your date generator code inside the callback so that it executes every time a request is received. 
The reason it doesn't work is that the code outside the callback only runs once and it
s value is not recalculated when you read it.

```
app.get( "/time_in_minutes", (req, res) => {
  var d = new Date();
  var key_1 = d.getMinutes();
  res.json(key_1.toString());    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could actually put the variable inside the callback function but there's a problem out there that needs to be solved:

```js
app.get( "/time_in_minutes", (req, res) => {
  var d = new Date();
  var key_1 = d.getMinutes();
  res.json(key_1.toString());
});
```

Let's suppose two users requesting the same route in the same time and they're going to insert the `key_1` value into a database. this will cause some user to overwrite the other user's value, eventually thats why express sessions are made for!

here's the npm package link: [express-session package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)